# Why gdal_calc.py returns 0 (Zeros) instead of NaN in the output?

Tags: null, gdal-calc

Why this gdal command returns 0 (zeros) instead of NaN in the outfile?

`gdal_calc.py -A aa.tif --outfile="out.tif" --type=Float64 --NoDataValue=nan --co="COMPRESS=DEFLATE" --format GTiff --calc="(A>-1.2)*(A)+(A<=-1.2)*(isnan(A))"`

0 (zero) is valid value in the dataset in this case. Therefore I cannot set --NoDataValue=0.

I know a workaround: I could force the command to use some out-of-range value (e.g. to -9999), but that is just not nice solution.

`gdal_calc.py -A aa.tif --outfile="out.tif" --type=Float64 --NoDataValue=-9999 --co="COMPRESS=DEFLATE" --format GTiff --calc="(A>-1.2)*(A)+(A<=-1.2)*(-9999)"`

What am I doing wrong to set NaNs in the gdal_calc output correctly? Do I miss something?

Comment: FYI, I found the solution with numpy syntax, e.g. `gdal_calc.py -A aa.tif --outfile="out.tif" --type=Float64 --co="COMPRESS=DEFLATE" --format GTiff --calc="numpy.where(A>-1.2,A,numpy.nan)"`